# jQuery .next().slideToggle() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have am creating my own comments system from scratch. The comments themselves are dynamically generated from those in the database and for each comment I am appending a reply textarea and button for the user to post a reply to someone's comment.

The problem is that when I click the reply link it opens a reply box for each comment not just for the comment the user wishes to reply to.

The HTML:

```
<a class="comment-reply">Reply</a>

<!--REPLY BOX -->
<div class="reply-box clearfix">
    <?php if($signed_in) { ?>
    <!-- reply input textarea -->
    <div class="container">
        <form id="reply-form">
            <textarea id="reply" rows="1" placeholder="Your reply here..."></textarea>
            <p><input id="reply-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary floatL" value="Post reply" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    //hide reply box on page load
    $('.reply-box').hide();

    //show each individual reply box on click
    $('.comment-reply').click(function() {
        //$('.reply-box').stop().slideToggle("fast"); /* This opens all div */
        $(this).next('.reply-box').stop().slideToggle("fast"); /* This doesn't work at all */
    });
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

edit

---

Ok this is the full HTML:

```
 <!--POSTED COMMENT-->
                <div id="comment-<?php echo $comment_id; ?>" class="media">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <a href="#"><img style="height: 48px; width: 48px;" src="<?php echo $c_member_avatar; ?>" class="img-rounded" alt=""></a>
                        <div style="font-size:1.2em">
                            <a style="color: #888888;" href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a style="color: #888888;" href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 style="margin: 0 0 5px 0;"><a href="#"><?php echo $c_member_username; ?></a><small>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $comment_timestamp; ?> ago</small><small style="margin-right: 20px;" class="floatR"><a id="comment-flagged" href="#"><span style="color: #5A5A5A" title="Flag as inappropriate" class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span></a></small></h5>
                    <p class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><?php echo $commentPosted; ?></p>
                    <?php if($signed_in && $username == $c_member_username) { ?>
                        <small class="floatL"><a class="comment-reply" id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>" >Reply</a></small>
                        <small class="floatL"><a class="comment-remove" id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>">Remove comment</a></small>
                    <?php } else if($signed_in) { ?>
                        <small class="floatL"><a class="comment-reply" id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>" >Reply</a></small>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <small class="floatL"><a href="signin.php" class="ilightbox" id="signin-reply" data-options="width:310, height:300">Sign in to reply to this comment</a></small>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--END POSTED COMMENT-->

                <!--REPLY BOX -->
                    <div class="reply-box clearfix">
                        <?php if($signed_in) { ?>
                        <!-- comment input textarea -->
                        <div id="comment-box" class="container">
                            <form id="reply-form">
                                <textarea id="reply" rows="1" placeholder="Your reply here..."></textarea>
                                <p style="padding-top: 15px;"><input id="reply-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary floatL" value="Post reply" /></p>
                                <p style="color:red; padding-left: 140px;" id="error"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                <!--END REPLY BOX-->
```

don't mind the styling, I am still prototyping

---

edit - added rendered page

---

```
<!--POSTED COMMENT-->
                <div id="comment-139" class="media">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <a href="#"><img style="height: 48px; width: 48px;" src="members/nicklaw/assassin_creed_black_flag _2-140x140.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt=""></a>
                        <div style="font-size:1.2em">
                            <a style="color: #888888;" href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a style="color: #888888;" href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 style="margin: 0 0 5px 0;"><a href="#">nicklaw</a><small>&nbsp;&nbsp;9 seconds ago</small><small style="margin-right: 20px;" class="floatR"><a id="comment-flagged" href="#"><span style="color: #5A5A5A" title="Flag as inappropriate" class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span></a></small></h5>
                    <p class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom:0px;">this is a comment</p>
                                                <small class="floatL"><a class="comment-reply" id="139" >Reply</a></small>
                        <small class="floatL"><a class="comment-remove" id="139">Remove comment</a></small>
                                            </div>
                </div>
                <!--END POSTED COMMENT-->

                <!--REPLY BOX -->
                    <div class="reply-box clearfix">
                                                    <!-- comment input textarea -->
                        <div id="comment-box" class="container">
                            <form id="reply-form">
                                <textarea id="reply" rows="1" placeholder="Your reply here..."></textarea>
                                <p style="padding-top: 15px;"><input id="reply-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary floatL" value="Post reply" /></p>
                                <p style="color:red; padding-left: 140px;" id="error"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                </div>
                <!--END REPLY BOX-->
```

Comment: Can't see the problem. I think it's working. Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkLD5/)

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fjL5L/1/

Comment: It works for me too: http://jsfiddle.net/WbLV8/

Comment: Remotely guessing this part could be is the problem `<script>` unless you're using HTML5. Try using `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: @thebitguru Both chrome and firefox

Comment: @NicholasLaw it is not html, it is php, change it to rendered page.

Comment: @eicto I'm not sure what you mean by 'rendered page'?

Comment: @NicholasLaw page without `<?php` - copied from browser source, not from your php source. one which possible to use in jsfiddle,

Comment: Can you share a sample "rendered" html (i.e. after php processes it)?

Comment: ok added the rendered html

Comment: Can you accept the answer if appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code will help, I am using the parentElement of the current element and then get the textarea that is in the same group. When attaching the click handler I use a div with class comments-container and attach on click only for anchors (second parameter in the `.on` function).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="comments-container">
      <div class="comment">
        Comment1
        <a href="#">comment</a><br>
        <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        Comment2
        <a href="#">comment</a><br>
        <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        Comment3
        <a href="#">comment</a><br>
        <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $("textarea").hide();
      $(".comments-container").on("click","a",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $("textarea").hide();
          $(this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0])
            .stop().slideToggle("fast");
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the .reply-box is not at the same level in the DOM as the .comment-reply link that is clicked (i.e. not a *sibling*).  If you see the [documentation for .click](http://api.jquery.com/next/) you will see that it only searches the *siblings*.

I think you want the `.parents(".media").next(".reply-box")`